# Perl - looping through two arrays to find "gaps"

Tags: perl

So my code setup is as per below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# vim: set expandtab ts=2 bg=dark smartindent shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 :
#

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
####use warnings;
use 5.010;


####my @arr1 = ( "0", "1", "2", "3", "4");    # OK
my @arr1 = ( "0", "1", "3", "4");             # Gap-1... seq2
my $arr1_len = scalar @arr1;
##
my @arr2 = ( "0", "1", "2", "3", "4");        # OK
####my @arr2 = ( "0", "1", "3", "4");         # Gap-2... seq2
my $arr2_len = scalar @arr2;
```

I am trying to loop through each list and compare it with eachother and detect any gaps in the sequence (the values are seq numbers of each stream - at the moment they are sequential, but they dont need to be/ wont be in the real world example)

EFFORT 1= if I use an inner for loop for arr2, it always starts at indx 0 - i.e. the pointer/ count doesn't tick on after we have a match

EFFORT 2= if I do a fake inner/ arr2 loop then I can't go to the next j without increasing the i counter

... I suspect there must be a simple way to do this - but I can't figure it out

**EFFORT 1**

```
ARR1: for (my $i=0; $i <= ($arr1_len-1); $i++) {
  print "i[$i]=$arr1[$i]\n";

  ARR2: for (my $j=0; $j <= ($arr2_len-1); $j++) {
    print "... j[$j]=$arr2[$j] -- ((i[$i]=$arr1[$i]))\n";

    # seq num match
    if ( $arr1[$i] eq $arr2[$j]){
      print "MATCH of seq_num [$arr1[$i]|$arr2[$j]]\n";
      shift @arr2;
      next ARR1;
    } # end of seq num match

    # gap in arr2
    if ( $arr1[$i] < $arr2[$j]){
      print "GAP in new [$arr1[$i]|$arr2[$j]]... New Missing $arr1[$i]\n";
      next ARR1;
    } # end of gap in arr2

    # gap in arr1
    if ( $arr2[$j] < $arr1[$i]){
      print "GAP in old [$arr1[$i]|$arr2[$j]]... Old Missing $arr2[$j]\n";
      next ARR2;
    } # end of gap in arr1
  } # end of j loop
} # i loop
```

**EFFORT 2**

```
my $j = 0;

ARR1: for (my $i=0; $i <= ($arr1_len-1); $i++) {
  print "i[$i]=$arr1[$i]\n";

  if ( $j <= ($arr2_len-1) ) {
    print "... j[$j]=$arr2[$j] -- ((i[$i]=$arr1[$i]))\n";

    # seq num match
    if ( $arr1[$i] eq $arr2[$j]){
      print "MATCH of seq_num [$arr1[$i]|$arr2[$j]]\n"; 
      $j++;
      next ARR1;
    } # end of seq_num match

    # probable gap in arr2
    if ( $arr1[$i] < $arr2[$j]){
      print "GAP in new [$arr1[$i]|$arr2[$j]]... New Missing $arr1[$i]\n";
      next ARR1;
    } # end of gap in arr2

    # probable gap in arr1
    if ( $arr2[$j] < $arr1[$i]){
      print "GAP in old [$arr1[$i]|$arr2[$j]]... arr1 Missing $arr2[$j]\n";
      # CANT NEXT J WITHOUT INCREASING I  ?!?
    } # end of gap in arr1

  } # end of fake j loop!
} # end of i loop
```

Comment: For non sequential values, you need something like [Algorithm::Diff](http://p3rl.org/Algorithm::Diff) that finds the Longest Common Subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

> The definition of a hole or a gap is only if it's in arr1 and not arr2 - or vice-versa... and I need to figure this out in an iterative manner (as when there is a match I then do some more examination of those data objects)

Hash tables are your friend. Something like this snippet:

```
use List::Util qw/max/;
my %hash1 = map { $_ => 1 } @arr1;
my %hash2 = map { $_ => 1 } @arr2;
my $len = max($arr1[$#arr1], $arr2[$#arr2]);
for my $n (0 .. $len) {
  if (exists $hash1{$n} and exists $hash2{$n}) {
    # n is in both lists
  } elsif (exists $hash1{$n}) {
    # n is only in the first one.
  } elsif (exists $hash2{$n}) {
    # n is only in the second one.
  } else {
    # Not in either one
  }
}
```

might do the trick for you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but [Set::IntSpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) can detect 'holes' in s sequence (even if unordered)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Set::IntSpan;

my @arr1 = ( 0, 1, 3, 4);

my $set = Set::IntSpan->new(@arr1);

print $set->holes;
```

Prints: 2

Comment: Thanks for the thought Chris (and a nice one to know of for the future)... but it won't help me here - as I expect non-sequential values really (its just sequential for the example). The definition of a hole or a gap is only if it's in arr1 and not arr2 - or vice-versa... and I need to figure this out in an iterative manner (as when there is a match I then do some more examination of those data objects)